# Does g++ work without gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Does G++ compile without GCC or G++ is just translator // Including old g++ version.

when i was trying to install g++ from source i saw file

> gcc.c

```
/* Default prefixes to attach to command names.  */

#ifndef STANDARD_EXEC_PREFIX
#define STANDARD_EXEC_PREFIX "/usr/local/lib/gcc-"
#endif /* !defined STANDARD_EXEC_PREFIX */
```

//from g++1.4*

Well i know that c++ is c with classes i just wanted to know if the g++ can compile c++ without gcc .

Comment: *Well i know that c++ is c with classes*. No. And why don´t you try to compile, if you have the source ready?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), `gcc` (actually `cc1` which is run by `gcc`) and `g++` (actually `cc1plus`)  -and so on for other GCC compilers, e.g. `gfortran` or even `gdc` ....- share a lot of (source) code together: the middle-end (where most optimizations happen) and the back-end. The difference is only the front-end layer of the compiler (the only layer being source language specific) which is less than 30% of the compiler.

<sup>You could customize the GCC compiler with plugins or with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/). Your extensions would work on GCC internal representations (Gimple-s) and would work when compiling C, C++, Ada, Fortran, etc... Remember that *GCC* means *Gnu Compiler Collection* today</sup>

Actually the `gcc` program is able to compile C++ source code (and likewise `g++` can compile C or Fortran code). However, they are not linking the same libraries.

Pass the `-v`  flag to the `gcc` or `g++` command to understand what they are running.

---

Here are two (mine) [CC-BY-SA] pictures -explaing GCC & MELT- illustrating this.

#### The three layers -front-end, middle-end, back-end- of the compiler:

with your plugin, or the [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) meta-plugin

[image: Three layers of GCC]

<sup>with a simplification: `cc1` or `cc1plus` are generating assembler files, which is then translated by `as` started by `gcc` or `g++`</sup>

and

#### another view of the internals of `cc1` or `cc1plus`,

which generates some assembler code

[image: view of <code>cc1</code> or <code>cc1plus</code>]

Comment: well (Merci Bcp c`est gentil) i asked this question because i am trying to make a programming language from scratch & i have a little background on this i made one based on C & the same lang based on 32-asm it is just like two compilation like the C based my own compiler translate it to c then gcc will do the work but after that i wanted to make something big that lang with one compiler & the asm 1st i made it with gcc -S then let NASM do the work after that i learn a bit of Assembly & i made without C (i am under 20 year) & now i am trying to figure out what is hidden in those compiler

Comment: If you are trying to make your own programming language, read [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) about translating your language to C.

Comment: thanks but i already have done this & i read so many books ...etc & some LLVM topics