# Linux Cpp project development environment with its own version g++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

I am wondering is it possible to **pack** a version of **g++** with a Cpp project **development environment**? Then this dev environment will not rely on the local machine's **g++ installation** which may be a different version.

I did this in **Java** project to include a **JDK** with the project and entire team will use the same **JDK** no matter what is on the local machine.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Today, the preprocessor is a part of the compiler: `gcc` does not run a `cpp` process, but only a  `cc1` one. And `cc1` contains the preprocessor, the parser, the middle-end optimization passes and back-end emission passes. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26167384/841108). BTW you could have several versions of `g++` and of `clang` on your Linux system.

Comment: @Jerry, any info\links on how to do it?

Comment: If you use a shell, you need to ensure the path is set up with your g++ before any other that might be on the system. g++ also uses some environment variables (CPATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH, etc.) that you need to point at your system include directories and ld uses LIBRARY_PATH to find libraries. These are all in the docs though...